# Observable not firing when used with combineLatest

Tags: angular

I'm using a combineLatest to bring together 3 different streams:

```
search$ = combineLatest({
    sortFormData: this.sortByFormListenSubscription$,
    cookieData: this.onlineAdvisorDetail$,
    queryParamData: this.queryParams$
  })
```

However I'm having a problem with my `this.sortByFormListenSubscription$` subscription:

```
sortByFormListenSubscription$ = this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    tap((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    }),
    map((x) => {

    let myData = {
      "sort_by": x.sortBy.by,
      "sort_order": x.sortBy.order
    }
    return myData;
  }),
  startWith({ "sort_by": "program-name", "sort_order": "asc" })
  );
```

When I change the value via my dropdown, the console log (in my tap) doesn't fire (nor do I get the new values). Any ideas why?

For reference my form set-up looks like this:

```
myForm: FormGroup = this.fBuilder.group({});

  sortOptions = [
    {by: 'program-name', order: 'asc', name: "Program name (A-Z)"},
    {by: 'program-name', order: 'dsc', name: "Program name (Z-A)"},
    {by: 'country-name', order: 'asc', name: "Country (A-Z)"},
    {by: 'country-name', order: 'dsc', name: "Country (Z-A)"},
    {by: 'duration', order: 'asc', name: "Duration (shortest first)"}
  ];

ngOnInit(): void {
this.myForm = this.fBuilder.group({
      sortBy: [this.sortOptions[0]]
    });
}
```

Comment: first: you should call it `sortByFormListenObservable` or `sortByFormListen$`  since it's an Observable and not a Subscription. That said, do you call `search$.subscribe()` or use the `async` pipe somewhere?  does `onlineAdvisorDetail$` and `queryParams$` work properl?

Comment: @Zerotwelve thanks good mention I'll change the name. The search$ uses async on the template. It's all working as expected on the initial render, it can even uses the initial values I'm using in the startWith. But it just ignores when I change the selection in the dropdown.

Comment: @Zerotwelve I've tracked down the problem. With valueChanges you MUST subscribe which of course I can't do because combineLatest only takes observables. I think only way I can do it is have a behaviourSubject, use that as the observable of the form value and put on a manual (change) on the form field itself.

Comment: hmmm strange. because you have an `| async` so you are indirectly subscribing to `valueChanges`. But honesty I can't tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Zerotwelve no probs thanks for your efforts anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get the documentation for your `combineLatest`?
The current [implementation](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) of `combineLatest` takes an Array of Observable which are combined.

And then the most common problem that occurs, is that combineLatest only emits a value once every single of its source observables emited at least one value.
Are you sure that both `onlineAdvisorDetail$` and `queryParams$` emited something?

Also namingwise: `sortByFormListenSubscription$` seems to be an `Observable` and not a `Subscription`, be sure to make clear what you are working with .

Comment: Thanks good point about the naming I'll change that. I've always used combineLatest by mapping it into an object, never had any problems. onlineAdvisorDetail$ and queryParams$ definitely emit a value. Everything works as it currently does with the initial render. It's just when I attempt to change the dropdown value it ignores the change.

Comment: Andrew is correct, you can pass an object to combineLatest. That't not the problem

Comment: Good thing I asked, never saw that and now I am in awe :D

Comment: @Chund I see lots of people doing it the array way and then they painfully manually map it afterwards which of course they don't need to do.

Comment: @Chund you can do the same with `forkJoin`, very usefull!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I love answering these questions for the things I learn from the responses <3